# How to set my default version in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, versions, multiple-versions

I'm working on a google app engine app that, after a lot of progress, has multiple versions deployed. I'd really like to switch the default version, which is the very first version of the app, to something more recent, but there doesn't seem to be any way to actually do that.

This article https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/06/25/harnessing-the-power-of-versions-on-app-engine/ claims there is a "Make Default" button under the version tab, but shows an older version of the console.

In the new version of the development console, there is no such button. This seems like an extremely key feature, and I'm not sure why they've obfuscated it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can use "Migrate traffic" feature to tell App Engine which version should receive 100% of all requests.

If, at some point, you may want to test a new version, you have an option of splitting all incoming requests between two or more versions of your app.