# In App Engine Flexible Environment, how can I see which Version of a Service is the default?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible, google-flexible

In Google App Engine Flexible Environment, I'd like to see which Version of my Service is the default.

The *list* operation of the Admin API does not show it:

```
https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/myapp/services/myservice/versions
```

Neither does the *get* operation:

```
https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/myapp/services/myservice.versions/myverson
```

In the Google App Engine API, I can use

```
ModulesService modulesService = ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService();
String currentModuleName = modulesService.getCurrentModule();
String version = modulesService.getDefaultVersion(currentModuleName);
```

But that is not available in Flexible Environment.

How do I do this in the Admin API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because App Engine has stopped referring to a specific version as the default one.

[App Engine seems to have no way to set a default version of a service since they replaced it with the feature of "Migrate traffic".](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37472662/6017784)

You can use the [`apps.services.get`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services/get) method to get the current traffic split for a service.